# Postgres - Is date in set of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I am trying to exclude rows that have a starts_at time on certain days. starts_at is a timestamptz.

My first attempt at the query is

```
SELECT event.id, event.starts_at
FROM event
WHERE to_char(event.starts_at::date, "YYYY-MM-DD") in ("2017-05-26", "2017-05-28")
```

My second attempt

```
SELECT event.id, event.starts_at
FROM event
WHERE event.start_at in '{2017-05-26, 2017-05-28}'::date[]
```

I am running this all in psql, and cannot figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a fallback you could just use `WHERE event.starts_at = '2017-05-26' OR event.starts_at = '2017-05-28'`

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
SELECT
    event.id,
    event.starts_at
FROM event
WHERE date_trunc('day', event.starts_at)::date IN ('2017-05-26', '2017-05-28')
```